# Typescript error - Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having a typescript error with my Ionic/Angular application. Below it says:

> Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type.

Which I don't understand. The entire error is:

> [17:57:57]  typescript: C:/xampp/htdocs/project x/anonymous-social/src/pages/threads/threads.ts, line: 58
>               Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type.
>
> L58:            let threadId = Object(snapshot.val()[Object.keys(snapshot.val())]).threadId;
>
> L59:            let messageCount = snapshot.val().unread || 0;

My code that goes along with this is:

```
this.database.database.ref('/users/'+this.userData.uid+'/threads/')
.orderByChild('threadId')
.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      let threadId = Object(snapshot.val()[Object.keys(snapshot.val())]).threadId;
      let messageCount = snapshot.val().unread || 0;
      rec.push(Object(snapshot.val()[Object.keys(snapshot.val())]));
```

Any idea why this might be happening? I don't completely understand... Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `snapshot.val()[Object.keys(snapshot.val())]` you are attempting to index into `snapshot.val()` using `Object.keys(snapshot.val())`.

`Object.keys` returns type `string[]`.

Is there a reason you can't just use:

```
let threadId = snapshot.val().threadId;
```

I don't see the need for all that extra logic.

Comment: Yes, `snapshot.val()` returns the first line in this image: https://i.gyazo.com/6eddab7527e3737cb1f72b96c040d6fe.png and the Object keys stuff returns the second line...

Comment: What is the expected shape of the snapshot value? It kinda sounds like you expect it only ever to have a single key-value pair and you expect `Object.keys` to give you the one key. But `Object.keys` returns an array of keys. If you are really sure it will have one, then you can change that to `Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]` and TS will be okay with it, but I stand by the opinion that there is a lot of unnecessary complexity here.